# Error #1065: Variable mx.core::RSLData is not defined

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm attempting to use loadStyleDeclarations on a remote SWF with the following code (using Flex 4.6):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView" initialize="GetFonts()">

    <fx:Script>
        public function GetFonts():void {
            styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("http://dev.mycompany.com/fonts/fonts.swf");
            fontLabel.setStyle('fontFamily', 'Arial');
        }   
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="fontLabel" text="This should be Arial!" top="10" />
</s:View>
```

As a Flex web application, this works perfectly (both the target swf and the consuming application on the same server, different folders). As a Flex mobile (iOS) application, an error is encountered:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable mx.core::RSLData is not defined.
    at style_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory/info()[style_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory.as:77]
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexModuleFactory.as:107]
    at style_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory()[style_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory.as:35]
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.modules::ModuleBase could not be found.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::FontAsset could not be found.
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable style__embed__font_Arial_medium_normal_657631602 is not defined.
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _class_embed_css_Assets_swf_1392078518_mx_skins_cursor_BusyCursor_762190923 is not defined.
```

Any ideas? Found one solution to add "-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true" to the build path but that did not resolve the issue.